# "Blob is not defined" using react-media-recorder in Astro project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-mediarecorder, astrojs

I have an Astro project with some React components, and I am trying to use [react-media-recorder](https://github.com/DeltaCircuit/react-media-recorder).

My code is pretty simple, a React component put into an Astro page:

```
import { useReactMediaRecorder } from "react-media-recorder";

function RecordButton() {
    const { status, startRecording, stopRecording, mediaBlobUrl } = useReactMediaRecorder({
        video: false,
        audio: true,
        onStop: () => {
            console.log("stopped recording");
            generateTranscript(mediaBlobUrl);
        }
    });
    // ...
```

As soon as I put this `useReactMediaRecorder` hook in my code, I get a ReferenceError `Blob is not defined`. This is browser-facing though, so I don't think I should have to install Blob in this file? But maybe I'm wrong. How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you using an ancient browser by chance?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by setting the component in Astro to `client:only` and ensuring that my Node was 18+!